# Unique nested dictionary from the 'for' loop Python3

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, nested, unique

I've got the host which executes commands via 'subprocess' and gets output list of several parameters. The problem is that output can not be correctly modified to be translated to the dictionary, whether it's yaml or json. After list is received Regexp takes part to match valuable information and to perform grouping. I am interested in getting a unique dictionary, where crossing keys are put into nested dictionary.

Here is the code and the example of output list:

```
from re import compile,match

#       Output can differ from request to request, the "keys" from the      #
#   list_of_values can dublicate or appear more than two times. The values  #
#   mapped to the keys can differ too.                                      #

list_of_values = [
    "paramId: '11'", "valueId*: '11'", 
    "elementId: '010_541'", 'mappingType: Both', 
    "startRng: ''", "finishRng: ''", 
    'DbType: sql', "activeSt: 'false'", 
    'profile: TestPr1', "specificHost: ''", 
    'hostGroup: tstGroup10', 'balance: all', 
    "paramId: '194'", "valueId*: '194'", 
    "elementId: '010_541'", 'mappingType: Both', 
    "startRng: '1020304050'", "finishRng: '1020304050'", 
    'DbType: sql', "activeSt: 'true'", 
    'profile: TestPr1', "specificHost: ''",
    'hostGroup: tstGroup10', 'balance: all']

re_compile_valueId = compile(
    "valueId\*:\s.(?P<valueId>\d{1,5})"
    "|elementId:\s.(?P<elementId>\d{3}_\d{2,3})"
    "|startRng:\s.(?P<startRng>\d{1,10})"
    "|finishRng:\s.(?P<finishRng>\d{1,10})"
    "|DbType:\s(?P<DbType>nosql|sql)"
    "|activeSt:\s.(?P<activeSt>true|false)"
    "|profile:\s(?P<profile>[A-z0-9]+)"
    "|hostGroup:\s(?P<hostGroup>[A-z0-9]+)"
    "|balance:\s(?P<balance>none|all|priority group)"
)

iterator_loop = 0
uniq_dict = dict()
next_dict = dict()

for element in list_of_values:
    match_result = match(re_compile_valueId,element)
    if match_result:
        temp_dict = match_result.groupdict()
        for key, value in temp_dict.items():
            if value:
                if key == 'valueId':
                    uniq_dict['valueId'+str(iterator_loop)] = ''
                    iterator_loop +=1
                    next_dict.update({key: value})
                else:
                    next_dict.update({key: value})
                    uniq_dict['valueId'+str(iterator_loop-1)] = next_dict

print(uniq_dict)
```

This code right here responses with:

```
{
    'valueId0': 
    {
        'valueId': '194', 
        'elementId': '010_541', 
        'DbType': 'sql', 
        'activeSt': 'true', 
        'profile': 'TestPr1', 
        'hostGroup': 'tstGroup10', 
        'balance': 'all', 
        'startRng': '1020304050', 
        'finishRng': '1020304050'
        },
    'valueId1': 
    {
        'valueId': '194',
        'elementId': '010_541', 
        'DbType': 'sql', 
        'activeSt': 'true', 
        'profile': 'TestPr1', 
        'hostGroup': 'tstGroup10', 
        'balance': 'all', 
        'startRng': '1020304050', 
        'finishRng': '1020304050'
        }
            }
```

And I was waiting for something like:

```
{
    'valueId0': 
    {
        'valueId': '11', 
        'elementId': '010_541', 
        'DbType': 'sql', 
        'activeSt': 'false', 
        'profile': 'TestPr1', 
        'hostGroup': 'tstGroup10', 
        'balance': 'all', 
        'startRng': '', 
        'finishRng': ''
        },
    'valueId1': 
    {
        'valueId': '194',
        'elementId': '010_541', 
        'DbType': 'sql', 
        'activeSt': 'true', 
        'profile': 'TestPr1', 
        'hostGroup': 'tstGroup10', 
        'balance': 'all', 
        'startRng': '1020304050', 
        'finishRng': '1020304050'
        }
            }
```

I've also got another code below, which runs and puts values as expected. But the structure breaks the idea of having this all looped around, because each dictionary result key has its own order number mapped. The example below. The list_of_values and re_compile_valueId can be used from previous example.

```
for element in list_of_values:
    match_result = match(re_compile_valueId,element)
    if match_result:
        temp_dict = match_result.groupdict()
        for key, value in temp_dict.items():
            if value:
                if key == 'balance':
                    key = key+str(iterator_loop)
                    uniq_dict.update({key: value})
                    iterator_loop +=1
                else:    
                    key = key+str(iterator_loop)
                    uniq_dict.update({key: value})
print(uniq_dict)
```

The output will look like:

```
{
    'valueId1': '11', 'elementId1': '010_541',
    'DbType1': 'sql', 'activeSt1': 'false', 
    'profile1': 'TestPr1', 'hostGroup1': 'tstGroup10', 
    'balance1': 'all', 'valueId2': '194', 
    'elementId2': '010_541', 'startRng2': '1020304050', 
    'finishRng2': '1020304050', 'DbType2': 'sql', 
    'activeSt2': 'true', 'profile2': 'TestPr1', 
    'hostGroup2': 'tstGroup10', 'balance2': 'all'
    }
```

Would appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared that some documentation reading needs to be performed :D

The `copy()` of the `next_dict` under `else` statement needs to be applied. Thanks to thread:

[Why does updating one dictionary object affect other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29116226/why-does-updating-one-dictionary-object-affect-other)

Many thanks to answer's author @thefourtheye (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1903116/thefourtheye)

The final code:

```
for element in list_of_values:
    match_result = match(re_compile_valueId,element)
    if match_result:
        temp_dict = match_result.groupdict()
        for key, value in temp_dict.items():
            if value:
                if key == 'valueId':
                    uniq_dict['valueId'+str(iterator_loop)] = ''
                    iterator_loop +=1
                    next_dict.update({key: value})
                else:
                    next_dict.update({key: value})
                    uniq_dict['valueId'+str(iterator_loop-1)] = next_dict.copy()
```

Thanks for the involvement to everyone.